# It is possible to STOP a Thread in Activity?

Tags: android

I noticed that even when the application is closed, the thread is still running! How is it possble, it is the same behavior for Asnctask.
I thought all Thread were executed in the UIThread but apparently not, so if I understand correctly, an external thread is independent of UIThread?  Could you help me understand the architecture of execution of a Android application?

Here is a small program illustrating my point:

```
package com.example.thread;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ThreadActivity extends Activity {

    private final String TAG = "ThreadActivity";
    private TextView textView;
    private Button buttonStart;
    private Thread t = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_thread);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.screen_thread_textview);
        buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.screen_thread_button);
        buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startThread();
            }
        });

    }

    private void startThread() {

        if (t == null) {
            t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Message msg = handler.obtainMessage(i);
                        handler.sendMessage(msg);
                        Log.v(TAG, "Thread running: i=" + i);
                    }
                    t = null;
                }
            });
            t.start();
        }
    }

    private Handler handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            textView.setText("Thread running: i=" + msg.what);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.thread, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

And the Layout:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/screen_thread_textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="#AACCCCCC"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/screen_thread_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Start Thread" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you in advance for your clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought all Thread were executed in the UIThread

All the Threads run inside the same process (your application) but are indipendent from UI Thread. You can exit from your application but the process can survive if some thread is still running. Notice that a thread runs until the last line of code inside its run method is executed. If you want to stop you have to force the run to reach its end

```
private void startThread() {

    if (t == null) {
        t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            private boolean exit = false;

            public boolean setExit() {
              exit = true; 
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {

                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

                    if (exit) {
                       i = 10; 
                       continue;
                    } 

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Message msg = handler.obtainMessage(i);
                    handler.sendMessage(msg);
                    Log.v(TAG, "Thread running: i=" + i);
                }
                t = null;
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }
}
```

and inside `onPause()` you can call `t.setExit()`

Comment: Ok I know how to stop a thread, thanks. I just want to know why a thread is still alive when the app is killed???

Comment: the app is not killed. In order the process to be terminated all the not daemon threads have to finish its execution

Comment: Ok Thanks for clarifications :)

Comment: If you a good website to explain the architecture process, I am interested. thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30914/discussion-between-jarvis-and-blackbelt)

Answer (score 0):

To stop your thread, try :

```
if (t!=null){
    if (t.getState()==Thread.Runnable){
       t.interrupt();
    }
}
```

I never try to use those code, just read at [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html)

Comment: @Jarvis you can place bangandi's snippet inside onPause or onDestroy.

Comment: on the other hand, t.interrupt is not reliable at all! I suggest using global variable to track state of your activity. if (appActive) to wrap thread runner